# NumberTextBox issue when using constraints.pattern: "#%"

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I need to display a **percentage symbol** next to a value for a`NumberTextBox` (only appending % symbol, no conversion is require).

At the moment I am using `constraints: {pattern: "#%"}`, I have notice that dojo adds two zero digit to value, example:

```
value 100 displayed as 10000%
```

which is not wrong in my use-case, instead I would like to display it as:

```
value 100 displayed as 100%
```

Here a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2w3wx5rm/

I am pretty sure my use-case is atypical, but I would like to know if you know a solution or work around to this problem.

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox){
    new NumberTextBox({
          name: "programmatic",
          constraints: {pattern: "#%"},
          value: 100
    }, "programmatic").startup();
});
```

---

```
<label for="programmatic">Opacity:</label>
<input id="programmatic" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to achieve this behaviour:

### First Approach

Add **%** symbol out of text box so it looks like this

[image]

Try this in [JSFiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/2w3wx5rm/4/)

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/2w3wx5rm/4/
```

### Second Approach

As we see that the name of numberTextBox become the id of the displaying container so based on the id we can update the value.

Try this in [JSFiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/2w3wx5rm/6/)

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/2w3wx5rm/6/
```

Below snippet code will help you to understand this:

```js
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", 
"dojo/aspect", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox, on, dom, aspect){
    var numbertextBox = new NumberTextBox({
          name: "programmatic",
          constraints: {pattern: "#"},
          value: 100
    }, "programmatic");
    numbertextBox.startup();
    dom.byId(numbertextBox.name).value = numbertextBox.value + "%";
    on(numbertextBox, "blur", function(){
             dom.byId(numbertextBox.name).value = numbertextBox.value + "%";
        });
        on(numbertextBox, "focus", function(){         
             dom.byId(numbertextBox.name).value = parseInt(dom.byId(numbertextBox.name).value.replace('%',''));
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


<label for="programmatic">Opacity:</label>
<input id="programmatic" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, This is happening because there in a specific meaning of having **"%"** in a pattern for dojo **NumberTextBox**.

[image: Number Pattern Characters]

To know more details Please [click here...](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/numbersDates.html)

However I tried to figureout exact reason of having this and I noticed that actual textbox contains **100** in hidden format and dojo is adding one more container on top of this with formatted value which contains **10000%**.

> Below Image will explain this better

[image]

So If we need to add **"%"** in the textbox we need to find anyother workaround for this.

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I also have notice that dojo seems to have this feature at really low level, for example if you look as NumberTextBox you can see a reference to https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/number.js at line 82. Not sure how to work around this. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you. I tried to figure out some workaround to achieve this. below are other inputs... :)